# Do we ever use "treatment with" instead of "treatment of"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to understand the syntax/meaning in the following sentence:

> The poet was distinguished by concise treatment with the paraphernalia of fire that were characteristic of the genre.

My understanding of the sentence would require "[treatment](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treatment) of", but then I'm wondering whether I'm missing something.

Full context:

> Asclepiades of Samos, also called Sicelides (fl. 300-270 BC). Inventor of the Alexandrian erotic epigram (see ALEXANDRIA; MUSEUM), distinguished by concise and witty **treatment with** the paraphernalia of fire and Erotes that were to be so characteristic of later erotic epigram.

This being the article on Asclepiades of Samos in the *Oxford Classical Dictionary*.

Comment: There's some flexibility, but I'd use *of*, too. But fretting over a small word someone else used can be exhausting. However, I once earned 10 points on a college final for assembling 20 microscopic edits in the professor's textbook new edition. He asked for it.

Comment: Ha - a good catch, then! To be honest, I wouldn't be fretting over it if I didn't have to translate it - have to make sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the surrounding context? What is the source?

Comment: Does the paraphernalia need treatment? Or is something treated with the paraphernalia? or does the paraphernalia accompany the treatment like daytime TV accompanies bed-rest?

Comment: CONTEXT NEEDED!!!

Comment: Original post has been edited - text & context added.

Comment: It's still not clear. Is the subject matter fire, or is fire the material of the treatment?

Comment: That's all I've got, I'm afraid. That's all the text. Whatever comes next is not relevant, but so as to leave no doubts about it, I'll give the next sentence: "A strong influence on Callimachus, Posidippus and Hedylus". As I said, my understanding is that Asclepiades was known for the concise and witty way in which he used the paraphernalia of fire and Erotes in his poems - and the paraphernalia were to become a characteristic of the genre.

Comment: That is a translation. It has English mistakes in it. Authors treatment of a subject or matter.

Comment: @Lambie Why do you believe that it's a translation? I thought that the OCD's articles were written in English, and [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_Classical_Dictionary) that it is "in English".

Comment: True, the author has a very English name - meaning that, though an article can be written in English by a non-English speaker or even be translated from a different language, this particular one seems to have been written originally in English by a native speaker.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we ever use "treatment with" instead of "treatment of"?

Yes:

1. Treatment with antibiotics was ineffective.
2. Treatment of the disease was particularly cruel.

**With** and **of** are prepositions, which, followed by an NP, form an adjunct.

**With** introduces a contemporaneous instrument.

**Of** introduces an association with the previous noun phrase.

To simplify the example and create a sentence:

[The picture is of] Asclepiades of Samos, inventor of a form of epigram that is distinguished by concise and witty treatment *[of the subject]* **together with/accompanied by** the paraphernalia of fire and Erotes that were to be so characteristic of *the* later erotic epigram.

Comment: True; and this is what makes this so very confusing. Perhaps the text means - more or less - that Asclepiades was distinguished for the treatment (of something I have yet to figure out) with the paraphernalia etc. But as I said I just had to check whether the two prepositions might be interchangeable in some cases.

Comment: I have added to my answer.

Comment: In other words, you take the paraphernalia not as the means by which he treated the epigram, but as an accompaniment, so to speak. Will have to think about it. Thanks a lot.